Using SQL in an Excel workbooks exhibits strange behaviour until the device is rebooted
I have a macro that runs a a number of different SQL statements.  I use the same macro each day. The 1st step is I update the Pending worksheet. The 2nd step is to identify new contracts. New contracts are identified by a SQL statement that compares the Pending worksheet to the History worksheet.  Anything on the Pending worksheet that is not on the History worksheet is a new contract and is displayed on the New Contract worksheet.
The problem I'm having is that the 2nd steps takes a couple of minutes. When I look at the New Contracts worksheet, there are the same results as yesterday.
What I found is that I save the macro and then reboot the desktop computer. Once the reboot is finished, I open the macro and complete the 2nd step. I get the results I expect.
One thing I noticed is that when I close the macro, Excel is trying to open a copy of the macro. I close that macro and reboot and I'm good to go.
I don't understand why (1) I get the same results and (2) why is Excel opening another copy of the macro. I've developed macro for years and have not seen this behavior before.
Below is the code we use to open a connection and the SQL statement.  This is similar to other macros within this process and in other macros and we do not have the same issue with any other SQL or macro.
Any suggestions or ideas to prevent the reboot each day would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for taking the time to look at this question.......
Set WBMain = ActiveWorkbook
    
dBConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & WBMain.FullName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
    
dBcn.Open dBConn
    
 vsql = ""
 vsql = "select P.* from [Pending$] P " _
        & "where P.[REPAIR_ID] IN " _
        & "(select DISTINCT P.[REPAIR_ID] from [Pending$] P " _
        & "Left Join [History$] H on P.[REPAIR_ID] = H.[REPAIR_ID] " _
        & "where H.[REPAIR_ID] IS NULL and P.[REPAIR_ID] IS NOT NULL)"

dbRS.Open vsql, dBcn

Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To dbRS.Fields.Count - 1
    DoEvents
    Cells(1, i + 1).Value2 = dbRS.Fields(i).Name
Next i

Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset dbRS
    
dbRS.Close


What does this "Excel opening another copy of the macro" mean? Do you mean the workbook? To not reboot the computer, kill all Excel processes in the (Windows) Task Manager.

Excel can open a copy the workbook if it crashed before.

Unqualified ranges like Cells(1, i + 1) can cause subtle errors, better to specify the worksheet ie ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New Contract").Cells(1,i+1). Same with Range("A2"). Where are you clearing the previous result ? Is the workbook on local or network drive ?

Are you saving the file between steps 1 and 2?

@rotabor............how do I prevent Excel from opening that copy.  I;ve started opeing Task Manager and all I see is 1 instance of Excel.
When I close the macro, there is a pop-up that says something like, Excel is trying to open a copy.  The 2 options, I believe are (1) Read or (2) Cancel.  Either options opens the second workbook; which I just close

@CDP1802....(1) When Step 2 is executed, the macro deletes the New Contracts worksheet, adds a new worksheet, calls it New Contracts.  (2) the workbook is stored on the desktop's C:\ drive since the network can be painfully slow at times.
I've started specifying worksheets in macros I develop but this is code I inherited.  I'll go back and look at specifying the worksheets like you suggest

@TimWilliams........I am not saving the macro workbook between steps 1 and 2

Is the file read-only? Can you manually copy it to the different location, delete from the original location and then copy to the original location? Do you open it from the network location?

The data is in the same file as the macro, or a different file?  It would be the file with the data updated in Step 1 which may need to be saved before running Step 2.

We need more context of where this code resides in relation to data, what encapsulates this code block (Sub, Function, Sheet vs Workbook vs Standard Module, etc.), and how it is run given the strange need to keep saving the macro?

Are you using any Application.OnTime events elsewhere in your work?

@rotabor...........It is not read-only and it is open from a network location.  I have copied it and renamed it and the behavior remains the same.  Thanks

@parfait.............It resides in a standard module.  I only save the workbook once I'm finished with all of the steps

@CLR.....I'm not using Application.OnTime any where in the code.  Thanks
